# Is a memory of all possible permutations of a kilobyte block and pointers possible?

Tags: theory, pointers, storage, information-theory

This is a hard enough idea to wrap my head around and I would greatly appreciate any edits/help to get it more readable for those in-the-know.

Is it theoretically possible to have a hard drive that has saved on it one copy of every possible binary permutation of one kilobyte and then have the rest of the system simply create pointers to these locations?

Would a system made such a way be any faster than simply having information stored directly?

To explain another way, say instead of having sentences:

> "Hello, I'm Bob." and "That sandwich looks delicious."

...stored on the hard drive, we would have all permutations of the alphabet and other characters up to some number (say, 1000 characters or so), and then have store our sentences as something like:

> [Pointer#21381723]

Comment: You may wish to consider [How many unique English tweets are possible? How long would it take for the population of the world to read them all out loud?](http://what-if.xkcd.com/34/). You are dealing with very big numbers.

Comment: You might find it interesting how *git* works, called *content addressable*.

Comment: https://github.com/philipl/pifs Is based on the same principal as your idea, except instead of having all permutations of a kb, it uses pi.

Comment: Your pointers would have to be 1-kilobyte long. You could choose to not store the blocks that don't make sense in English - in which case you've independently reinvented the idea of compression!

Comment: Basic answer is NO - it's impossible due to the # and size of the permutations But what possible application were you thinking it would be useful for if it were possible??

Answer (score 91, accepted):

There are 2<sup>8192</sup> possible different 1K blocks. Storing them all would take 2<sup>8202</sup> bits of storage. Since the universe contains only about 10<sup>80</sup> (or ~2<sup>266</sup>) particles, it's a safe bet that it **isn't** possible to store them all, and you don't have to wonder about whether it would save time or not.

But there is, in fact a more interesting way of answering this. You are suggesting creating an index into a huge pool of constants. But how would you know which index to dereference? Imagine for the sake of an argument that you want to store only 1-character blocks: `a`, `b`, `c`... Presumably your indices would be 0, 1, 2 etc., since that's the most efficient layout of storing those blocks.

Do you notice something about the arrangement? Your index is, in fact, *a coded representation of the stored data*! In other words, you don't have to dereference at all, you just have to transform the index into the data you want.

When you store *all* possible values of something in a table, this always happens: your index becomes merely an encoded version of the data itself, so storing the data becomes unnecessary in the first place. This why in the real world, indices are only useful for sparse data (e.g. all web pages you've visited, not all web pages that *could exist*, or even all that *do* exist).

Comment: Typo in the amount of storage it would take? Seems like that should be 2^8192.

Comment: With the 10^80 limit of particles for the universe, doesn't this mean that it is literally impossible to for there to exist one copy of every permutation of a Kilobyte in the universe at any one time?

Apologies if this warrants another full "question" on SE.  I am unsure of the procedure for follow-up questions.

Comment: @8bittree No, a 1K block takes 2^10 bits to store. N blocks take N * 2^10 bits. 2^8192 blocks take 2^8192 * 2^10 bits, which equates to 2^(8192 + 10) bits.

Comment: @AmagiiDiscordusPenndragon This is turning philosophical.  It is impossible to store more than 10^80 *different pieces* of information.  In other words, while you couldn't store 10^80 pieces of information, you *could* still store the string "10^80" with merely 6 bytes.

Comment: @KilianFoth Ah, right, of course. The data itself isn't free.

Comment: @AmagiiDiscordusPenndragon Yes, it means exactly that. Combinatorial numbers are *really, really* big! This is why combinatorial algorithms are so valuable: they allow you to deal with any possible input without having to spell out each possible case.

Comment: @Neil - Indeed it is becoming philosophical and I find the facts presented here as both saddening and beautiful.

Comment: So, in a way, we're already using this system - but we're doing it with lazy evaluation of the kilobyte-sized bit patterns, which allows us to save *tons* of storage space!

Comment: The storage is slightly reduced, due to overlap (1024 zeros followed by 1024 ones contains 1025 unique patterns)... reduced but still impossibly large.  Also, a 1KB block is 2<sup>13</sup> bits, not 2<sup>10</sup>.

Comment: Your last example is somewhat poor, or perhaps misleading; web page indexing relies not on *pages* being sparse, but on *short substring commonality* between pages. These substrings are far less than 1 KiB, are sparse (because all language is sparse), and once indexed, can be used to link many pages with high cache locality.

Comment: Note that the 10^80 limit on particles in the universe doesn't *directly* mean you can't store more than, say, 10^80 bits in the universe - because with each particle you can potentially store more than one bit of information (based on its position within the universe, and possibly its velocity etc). That doesn't mean you *can* store every 1K block though - the number of those exceeds the number of particles by an astoundingly large factor, so it's still a very safe bet you can't store them all!

Comment: @Neil If you have a coding system that allows you to store 10^80 by encoding it as "10^80" then how do you store "10^80"? If some pieces of data are encoded shorter than the actual data, others have to be encoded longer. Or if all of your pieces of data are numbers, then you're storing each decimal digit as a whole byte.

Comment: With [de Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) 2^1024 bits would suffice.

Comment: @gronostaj I love de Bruijn Sequences, so anything related to them gets a +1. But unfortunately, 2^1024 is still exponentially more bits than we have in the universe. :/

Comment: @gronostaj: Not quite - there are 2^8192 different 1K blocks (1024 bytes * 8 bits) - so it will take at least 2^8192 bits :)

Comment: @psmears You're right, I think I assumed 1-bit bytes ;) Still, that's 1024 times less than 2^8202.

Comment: The universe is ~203 planck-lengths across.
Arrange all particles in a line in the Z axis. Then can store 203 bits/particle by moving each to a position in the X axis, and 203 by moving in the Y axis, for a total of 406 bits/particle.
Multiplying by 2^80 particles gives total approximate storage capacity of the universe as 2^486.

Call it 2^500 at most, if you use particle type, spin, charge and vertical Y position to encode a few more bits, too.

How you'd prevent gravity from scrambling your data, and how you'd read/write, are left as exercises for the reader.

Comment: @Random832 I meant that string "10^80" could be thought of as a representation of the number that it is meant to be.  We're not talking about all permutations of all information ever.  Just any combination of 1Kb.  Just because I represent the number 1000000 as 1160 (one 1, six 0s), doesn't mean you can't represent the number 1160 under that system.

Comment: Actually, you're not storing a "coded representation of the data"... You're storing the data itself! All permutations of a KB block are simply all integers from 0 to 8^1024, which coincidentally is also the number of indexable entries needed, so _key==value for all entries_. A pretty useless array :)

Comment: @Neil But it does mean that the number 1160 doesn't represent itself. And if some numbers are encoded as smaller numbers, then some other numbers have to be encoded as larger numbers.

Comment: @Random832 Yes, we're essentially talking about compression, which is precisely my point.  You can't hold 10^80 *different* pieces of information.

Comment: 10^80 particles in the *observable* universe. There are likely many more particle far away we can't see because the speed of light is too slow...

Comment: @DewiMorgan you live in a very very small universe. 203 L_P is 3E-23 Å.

Comment: @Davidmh Doh! Thanks for catching the typo, I meant 2^203! Sliiiightly different. Rest of the math remains unaffected though, 2^203 planck lengths means 203 bits/particle in x and y, for 2^80 particles, giving an optimistically rounded-up max of 2^500 bits of universal storage. Shame I can't edit old comments.

Comment: Related: [How many bytes can the observable universe store?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4118/405)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian link only comment, pfah.  The punch line is that the observable universe has a holographic information bound of E120.  To fit more information in the universe, you'd need to get a bigger universe.

Comment: **Comments are not meant for extended discussions.  Please continue the conversation in our chat room.  Thank you.**

Answer (score 20):

As others have already pointed out, you have 2^8192 possibilities for a 1k block. This means you would need 8192 bits to encode the address of a block if all blocks addresses are encoded with the same amount of bits, so your addresses would be 1k long. You wouldn't have gained anything except adding a layer of indirection so you wouldn't gain any performance.

If you wanted to have shorter addresses, you would have to encode some blocks with a short address and some with longer ones and make it so that long ones don't appear that often, and you are now simply compressing data (probably with something like a [Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)). That would require knowledge of the data you're storing before storing it or regular changes in the encoding. It would also probably be less efficient than other compression algorithms which use blocks of varying length.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with that.

First, "all possible binary permutations of one kilobyte" is a *huge* amount of data.  1024 bytes * 8 bits per byte = 8192 bits in a kilobyte.  All possible permutations would be 2^8192.  That's around `1.09e+2466` kilobytes!  (For purposes of comparison, a 1 TB drive is `1e09` kilobytes.)

Second, even if you did have such an enormous table, and you indexed into it with pointers, what would you do if you wanted to reference some data smaller than exactly 1 KB?

Comment: Storing all blocks smaller than 1 KB in addition will not take that much more space. Assuming only byte-sized blocks, the size of the smaller blocks together is just slightly over 1/256 of the size of the 1-KB-blocks. Assuming bit-sized blocks, you add about the same size again.

Answer (score -1):

As other posters have pointed out, at some point, the size of the pointer needed to index into your list of all possible values nullifies your gain.

However, some languages use a limited version of what you suggest in order to optimize memory usage.  Python uses string 'interning' to lessen the number of duplicate strings in memory.  You can find more information by searching for 'python string intern'.

Comment: The OP is asking about a dense set, containing every permutation.  Pointers are only useful for sparse data, where the bits required to hold a pointer are smaller than the bits pointed to.  Interning can make the space more sparse if there are duplicates, so there's a connection there, but your answer doesn't really phrase it well.